# Closed sets with empty interior measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is the Lebesgue measure of a closed set with empty interior in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ always zero?

Trying to understand something in the math notes that I don't understand, and if the above is true, it would make more sense. Not sure if true though!

Comment: Hint: Fat Cantor sets.

Comment: I guess the set of irrationals would also be an example.

Comment: @onurcanbektas no because he is asking for a closed set. The irrationals are not closed since their complement the rationals are not open.

Comment: @Shashi Even if we look the irrationals in $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas yep

Comment: @Shashi Ok, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just take

$$
U =\bigcup_n B_{1/2^n}(x_n),
$$

where $(x_n)_n$ is an enumeration of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Then $U$ is open an of finite measure, so that $A=U^c$ is closed and of positive (infinite) measure.

But the interior of $A$ is void, because it contains no point of $\Bbb{Q}$.

This example avoids having to understand the construction of the Cantor set.

Comment: Should we prove A is not empty?

Comment: @ZornSakawa: It is easy to see that $U$ has finite measure; in fact, $\lambda(U) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2/2^n =2$, where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. Hence, $\lambda(A) = \lambda(\Bbb{R}) - \lambda(U) = \infty$. In particular, $A \neq \emptyset$, since otherwise $\lambda(A) = 0$.

Comment: Why does it not contain point of  $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @mavavilj: $U \supset \Bbb{Q}$ (why?), And hence $A \cap \Bbb{Q} = \Bbb{Q} \setminus U = \emptyset$.

Comment: But shouldn't the complement of $U$ be at $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @mavavilj: Sure. But $\Bbb{Q} \cap A = \Bbb{Q} \cap (\Bbb{R} \setminus U) = \Bbb{Q} \setminus U$, as you can easily verify.

Comment: I don't get it. You're taking the intersection of the complement of $U$ with $\mathbb{Q}$, eventhough it's trivial that the complement will not contain $\mathbb{Q}$ points. This doesn't tell anything about the complement? Like why cannot irrational points be inner points for example?

Comment: @mavavilj: OK, this is what you are asking :) If you had an interior point $x$ of $A$, then $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \subset A$. But the interval on the left contains (infinitely many) rational numbers, while $A$ doesn't contain any.

Answer (score 3):

No. For example [Cantor-like set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), they are closed and nowhere dense, but they can have any measure in $(0,1)$.